# Why the last row of my intraday yfinance data is missing?

Tags: stock, yfinance

I used the following code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd


data = yf.download(tickers='EL',period='1d',interval='5m')


print(data.tail())
```

And the results I got:

```
[*********************100%%**********************]  1 of 1 completed
                                 Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  Volume
Datetime                                                                                     
2023-12-22 15:35:00-05:00  144.110001  144.270004  144.054596  144.100006  144.100006   19665
2023-12-22 15:40:00-05:00  144.000000  144.160004  143.925003  144.160004  144.160004   25930
2023-12-22 15:45:00-05:00  144.220001  144.240005  144.057007  144.070007  144.070007   33270
2023-12-22 15:50:00-05:00  144.130005  144.479996  144.119995  144.470001  144.470001   57425
2023-12-22 15:55:00-05:00  144.460007  144.529999  144.339996  144.429993  144.429993  133693
```

The last 5min data is missing. And if I try to download data for multi-days, the last 5 min data is missing for every day.

How to fix this? Thanks!

The code is above. I am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next data point is classified as the next day, hour, or whatever you’re sorting by. If that next five minutes was included, it would technically be data from the next day. You would have to query for the next (hour, day, etc.) to get that data point.